# Swift Change dimensions and position of existing Button/Label

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to programmatically change the dimensions and position of an existing button or label programmatically. The button that I want to edit is already in a ViewController and there are no constraints whatsoever in my app so far.

I have myButton instatiated with:

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
```

I've tried:

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0)
```

and

```
myButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
```

and

```
myButton.frame.width = 100
```

The first two of these lines of code have compiled and ran, but neither have changed any of the dimensions/positions of the button. The third line of code (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061033/change-width-to-a-iboutlet-uiimageview)) doesn't even compile because "width is a get only property."

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it an outlet? Is it linked properly to xib? Share more info please

Comment: TheNumberDevil The answer at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061033/change-width-to-a-iboutlet-uiimageview as you provide in your question, is not actually correct.

Comment: myButton is an IBOutlet. I accidentally left out the instantiation of the button (oops...) but it's there now.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, check that the button really is connected to that IBOutlet.

Comment: I rechecked the connection to the IBOutlet and it wasn't connected. Thanks for helping me double check my idiocy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two lines, especially first one should work, so you may have not connected them with IBOutlet, or if created programatically, may have not been instantiated properly.

While size is one of properties of the frame, you actually need to access this `size` property. So the third line needs to be updated like this:

```
myButton.frame.size.width = 100
```

Comment: Your code works and compiles, thanks! But It still isn't updating the button, maybe because it isn't being connected with the IBOutlet? Does the button have to be updated to the IBOutlet again after I instantiate it for the first time?

Comment: Lets check whether the issue is not only in frame modification. So add one more line under line myButton.frame = ... and the code would be myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor(). If the color doesn't change, it's definitely not connected properly. To your question: No, just once is needed to make a connection. If you would update your question adding some more pictures of storyboard or code, it could help me understand and solve your issue.

Comment: So I did myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() and what happened was that the background of the entire ViewController turned red instead of just the button turning red

Comment: So we'revery close. I suppose you missed your button whene you connected your IBOutlet and you ctrl dragged your view instead. Don't you? Remove the connection and try to do it again. OR: your button is expanded on the full width of the container view. In case nothing helps, post an image of your storyboard plz

Comment: I checked how the button was connected to the IBOutlet and it wasn't... so I guess I'm just an idiot.... thanks though!

Comment: It happens very often, it is not so difficult to make a mistake when creating this kind of enviroment, even with solid experience. Happy coding.

Comment: @TheNumberDevil So did my answer help you? :)